# TYPO 3 6.1: Change the rendering of a custom content element depending on the backend layout

Tags: typo3, typoscript, typo3-6.1.x

I try to write a custom content element which should be rendered depending on the backend_layout or the inherited backend_layout of the page the content element is contained in.

**My first attempt**

I've got theTypoScript snippet in my template:

```
lib.layout = CASE
lib.layout {
    key.field = backend_layout
    key.ifEmpty.data = levelfield:-1,backend_layout_next_level,slide

    1 = TEXT
    1.value = START-PAGE-LAYOUT

    2 = TEXT
    2.value = SINGLE-COLUMN-PAGE-LAYOUT

    3 = TEXT
    3.value = TWO-COLUMN-PAGE-LAYOUT

    default = TEXT
    default.value = DEFAULT-OUTPUT
}
```

If I try to render this in my plugin view like this

```
<f:cObject typoscriptObjectPath="lib.layout" />
```

I get

```
DEFAULT-OUTPUT
```

I would expect one of the other three as output.

**My second attempt**

I also tried

```
plugin.my_contentelement.settings.layout < lib.layout
```

and then to use the ContentObjectRenderer but got only the default output.

**My question**

Does anybody has a nice solution for my problem?

**PS: I use TYPO3 6.1.5**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`key.field` should work as by default the current data array is populated by the page data. I don't know why it doesn't work in your case so try this code instead:

```
lib.layout = CASE
lib.layout {
  key.data = page:backend_layout
  key.ifEmpty.data = levelfield:-2,backend_layout_next_level,slide

  1 = TEXT
  1.value = START-PAGE-LAYOUT

  2 = TEXT
  2.value = SINGLE-COLUMN-PAGE-LAYOUT

  3 = TEXT
  3.value = TWO-COLUMN-PAGE-LAYOUT

  default = TEXT
  default.value = DEFAULT-OUTPUT
}
```

For `levelfield:-1,backend_layout_next_level,slide` to work, you probably need to add  `backend_layout_next_level` (and better also `backend_layout`) to `$TYPO3_CONF_VARS['FE']['addRootLineFields']` in the installation config file.

Answer (score 1):

Shouldn't it be:

```
lib.layout = CASE
lib.layout {
```

Additionally you should replace ifEmpty with override and do it the other way around, since TSref says: *If the content is empty (trimmed) at this point, the content is loaded with "ifEmpty". Zeros are treated as empty values!*

```
lib.layout {
    key.data = levelfield:-2,backend_layout_next_level,slide
    key.override.field = backend_layout

    1 = TEXT
    1.value = START-PAGE-LAYOUT

    2 = TEXT
    2.value = SINGLE-COLUMN-PAGE-LAYOUT

    3 = TEXT
    3.value = TWO-COLUMN-PAGE-LAYOUT

    default = TEXT
    default.value = DEFAULT-OUTPUT
}
```

Setting it explicitely to "None" has a value other than zero, so this should be working.

Comment: I think that in this particular case both approaches work. If no backend layout is selected, its value is automatically `0` and thus with `ifEmpty` the content is considered empty and layout from some higher level is loaded. However, your approach should definetely work as I use it myself.

Comment: Btw, as for the `CASE`, I think he does use it as otherwise he probably wouldn't get the default value. It's good to mention it though.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to insert the line `lib.layout = CASE` into my posting

Comment: Actually the level slide has to start at -2, since -1 would be the current page and you don't want to use it's "backend layout on next level" for the page itself.

Comment: That's true. Very good point! +1 from me for bringing that up.